# How to rearrange matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix, reshape

I have data that I read in as a list:

```
#Data[0] = X1 Y1a Y2a Y3a Y4a
#Data[1] = X2 Y1b Y2b Y3b Y4b


for i in range(len(Data)): #len(Data) = 25, say
     X_data.append(Data[i][0])
     for j in range(int(math.sqrt(len(Data[0] - 1)))):
          Y_data.append(Data[i][j+1])
```

This gives me a Y_data list of length (4 * len(Data)) = 100

But instead of a single dimension list I want Y_data to be a 2x2(x25) list with:

```
Y_data[Xval_a][0][0] = Y1a
Y_data[Xval_a][1][0] = Y2a
Y_data[Xval_a][0][1] = Y3a
Y_data[Xval_a][1][1] = Y4a
```

where Xval is one of my 25 indicies from Data

I also want this to scale with how many Y data values I have. For example, here I have Y1 - Y4, so a 2x2 array is needed, but I could also have Y1 - Y9 or Y1 - Y16.

I have tried np.reshape but I don't seem to be using it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following work?

```
Data = np.array(Data)
Data = np.reshape(Data, (2,2,25))
```